# PC freezes after long period of inactivity (~> 30 min)

Tags: 12.04, laptop, freeze, suspend, lock-screen

My Ubuntu system is configured to turn off the screen and lock itself after 10 minutes of inactivity. (System settings ---> Brightness and screen lock).
If I leave the PC for about 10 mins or 15 mins, I just move the mouse and set the password, and I'm good to go. But if I leave my PC for let's say 30 mins or longer, then when I try to wake up the system by moving the mouse, everything freezes and the only option is to reset.

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
and my pc is a Acer aspire 5750G

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug,
[ubuntu 12.04 completely freezes frequently](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/993187)
You can also look at [ubuntu 12.04 freezes](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4030431)

Comment: The second link isn't particularly helpful. The "bug" has been marked "Won't Fix".