# after screen is inactive for 30 min it won't return, 17.04

Tags: suspend, 17.04

There is fairly recent problem with 17.04. I have always had my computer "Turn screen off when inactive for 30 minutes". The Lock button has always been off, and I don't require my password when waking from suspend.

This has always worked well. Moving the mouse or pressing a key wakes up the computer. Now if I leave the computer and come back later (>30 min), the screens are black as expected (I have dual screens). The problem is that I can't wake up the computer. I have to power off to get control back.

I see references in previous versions:
[PC freezes after long period of inactivity (~> 30 min)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248676/pc-freezes-after-long-period-of-inactivity-30-min)

[What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

but these don't help me.

To try to simulate the problem I set the turn off time to 1 min. The first time moving the cursor solved the problem, so I let it go for another minute. Then I pressed the escape key. The screens came back but the mouse was frozen. I tried a Ctrl-Alt-T to get a terminal, but the keyboard wasn't responding either.

Maybe I have no choice but to do a power down, but it would be nicer if I could somehow get control back but some other method.

I'm not sure if this is a suspend problem. Since it appeared only recently, I suspect it is connected to 17.04. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would like to ask if other users see this problem. My kernel has advanced and the problem remains. It is becoming more frequent.

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04. Impossible to do anything after it freezes, not even ctrl-alt-f1

Comment: I basically gave up on the problem, and chose the time to be never turn off the screen.

Comment: I have the same problem but it usually occurs if the display has been blanked for a day or two. Its very annoying.

Comment: Some very good news! The update to 17.10 with gnome in place of Unity solves the problem. Now I have the screen blank back to 15 min. An added advantage is Virtual box (the updated version for 17.10) works much nicer on my dual screen.