# Computer not taking input from mouse and keyboard

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, mouse, input-devices, input

Ubuntu 14.04 was working just fine. Today when I booted it is not taking any input from any keyboard and mouse. Since I had wireless keyboard and mouse I also tried with wired but didn't help. 
I have no clue how to fix it as it's not taking any input either at grub or in login screen.

Comment: I too faced similar issue... Try to boot into recovery mode with a different kernel, Worked for me.

Comment: Any links on how to do that  please ?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version hope your keyboard is working up to grub menu.

Comment: My keyboard is not working on Grub menu

Comment: I have a similar problem in 17.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/908623/after-screen-is-inactive-for-30-min-it-wont-return-17-04